# Send Rest API's Post Query which should be Sorted by formula

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-search, sorting, formula

I am trying to send a request using SharePoint 2013 Rest API (**POSTQUERY**)
and my sort-list is a formula. When I am sending a **GET** request, it works fine as mentioned in below example:

http://localhost/_api/search/query?querytext='home'&sortlist='[formula:abs(currentcity-deptlatcoord)+abs(currentcity-deptlongcoord)[:ascending'

but, I don't find on the correct syntax to send it on the post query object:

```
'request': {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchRequest' },
            'Querytext': '',
            'QueryTemplatePropertiesUrl': 'spfile://webroot/queryparametertemplate.xml',
            'StartRow': startRow,
            'RowsPerPage': '10',
            'SelectProperties': { 'results': [] },
            'RankingModelId': '576C7FC6-E765-4508-A45B-38FB4D2A61FC',
             'SortList' : formula:abs(currentcity-deptlatcoord)+abs(currentcity-deptlongcoord)]:ascending
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct syntax (maybe this will help someone):

```
'request': {
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchRequest' },
        'Querytext': '',
        'QueryTemplatePropertiesUrl': 'spfile://webroot/queryparametertemplate.xml',
        'StartRow': startRow,
        'RowsPerPage': '10',
        'SelectProperties': { 'results': [] },
        'RankingModelId': '576C7FC6-E765-4508-A45B-38FB4D2A61FC',
         'SortList' : 
              {
                 'results' : [
                               {
                              'Property':[formula:abs(currentcity-deptlatcoord)+abs(currentcity-deptlongcoord)]:ascending,
                             'Direction': '0'
                               }
                              ]
                 },

             }
```